# Why does a method subscribed to an event lose reference to its own class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

While I was working on my game I've noticed something very worrying about my code:

```cs
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F1))
        {
            hintFeedback.PlayFeedbacks();//<- this works
            DisplayHint();
           
        }
void DisplayHint()
    {
        OnHint.Invoke();
    }
initialise()
{
OnHint += HintCallback;
}


void HintCallback()
    {
        hintFeedback.PlayFeedbacks(); //<- this gives the error
             
    }
```

This gives in console a Missing Reference Exception

But the following code works:

```cs
void HintCallback()
    {
        TheClassOfHintFeedback.instance.hintFeedback.PlayFeedbacks(); //<- this works again
             
    }
```

Can someone explain what am I looking at here? the TheClassOfHintFeedback is a singleton.

Comment: what error do your get? Can you the code which can be compiled without any error and can be run to reproduce the issue on our own?

Comment: It gives a missing reference error. You dont think this is the intended behaviour in c#/Unity?

Comment: It looks like `hintFeedback` is not initialized before you try to access in the code. The class code is not complete so I am not able to understand the sequence.

Comment: Thats the whole code. Its Unity...